# Keras Sequential model, more inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, keras

I am quite new to machine learning and I am currently working on a "car value predictor" application. I stuck where I have to feed my data to my model. I have 4 inputs:

- date: the car's first registration date (int)
- km: the car's mileage meter (int)
- consume: the car's consume type (one-hot encoded vector with 10 element e.g. for petrol: [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0])
- type: the car's type (for example: "BMW-320", stored in one-hot encoded vector with 440 element )

and one output:

- the price of the car.

I would like to do something similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpYRo.jpg

I have tried the following code which compiles but the output is not what I wanted:

```
model = Sequential([
Dense(128, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu', name='date'),
Dense(128, input_shape=(1,), activation='relu', name='km'),
Dense(128, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu', name='consume'),
Dense(128, input_shape=(440,), activation='relu', name='type'),
Dropout(0.5),
Dense(128, activation='relu'),
Dropout(0.5),
Dense(1, activation='linear') 
])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit( x = {'date' : samples_train['input'][:,0],
                'km' : samples_train['input'][:,1],
                'consume':samples_train['input'][:,2],
                'type':samples_train['input'][:,3]},
           y = samples_train['output'],
           epochs=1000,
           batch_size=16,
           verbose=1, 
           validation_data = ({'date' : samples_valid['input'][:,0],
                               'km' : samples_valid['input'][:,1],
                               'consume':samples_valid['input'][:,2],
                               'type':samples_valid['input'][:,3]}, samples_valid['output']),
           callbacks=callbacks)
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong or how can I implement a model "structure" like on the picture?

## EDIT:

I think this is what I was looking for. Can anyone confirm this? :)

```
input_1 = Input(shape=(1,), name='date')           # input layers
input_2 = Input(shape=(1,), name='km')
input_3 = Input(shape=(10,), name='consume')
input_4 = Input(shape=(440,), name='type')
dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_1)   # hidden layers
dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_2)
dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_3)
dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_4)
dropout_1 = Dropout(0.5)(dense_1)
dense_2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(dropout_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense_2)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dropout_2) # output layer

model = Model([input_1,input_2,input_3,input_4], outputs)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your second Implementation is wrong.

By implementeing it like that, dense_1 will only have the value you gave it in the last line : `input_4 = Input(shape=(440,), name='type')` thus not taking into accunt the rest of the imputs for the rest of the network.

What you should do is concatenate your inputs into a single Line before feeding it to the first dense layer, like that :

```
from keras.layers import Concatenate

input_1 = Input(shape=(1,), name='date')           # input layers
input_2 = Input(shape=(1,), name='km')
input_3 = Input(shape=(10,), name='consume')
input_4 = Input(shape=(440,), name='type')

x = Concatenate()([input_1 , input_2 , input_3 , input_4]) # Concatenation of the inputs.

dense_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)   # hidden layers
dropout_1 = Dropout(0.5)(dense_1)

dense_2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(dropout_1)
dropout_2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense_2)

outputs = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dropout_2) # output layer

model = Model([input_1,input_2,input_3,input_4], outputs)
```

Comment: Now I understand, why my network looks like this:
[(model.summarize())](https://imgur.com/a/g83Paec)

Thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: Your implementation looks like: [(model.summarize())](https://imgur.com/a/rF0EMBT)